# Python putting non uniform lines into a dictionary

Tags: python, file, dictionary, readline

The input file looks like this:

```
A 3.00 B 4.00 C 5.00 D 6.00
E 3.20 F 6.00 G 8.22
H 9.00 
I 9.23 J 89.2
K 32.344
```

And I am wanting the characters to be the keys in a dictionary 
while the floats being the values.

Here is the non-working fail that I have so far.

```
def main():
   #Input File
   reader = open('candidate.txt', 'r'

   my_dictionary = {}
   i=0
   for line in reader.readlines():
      variable = line.split(' ')[i]
      value = line.split(' ')[i+1]
      my_dictionary[variable]= value
      i+=2

      print my_dictionary

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: Think about your code for a moment. `i` gets increased by 2 for each line, right? So you get the first pair from line 1, the second from line 2, and so on, which is clearly not what you want, right?  You need two nested for loops, one for lines and one to get all pairs within a line (if you want to keep using for loops - there are more efficient options, see guettli's answer for instance).

Comment: Basically, you need to iterate over items in your list in pairs (key, value). Here is an extensive answer showing different techniques: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628290/pairs-from-single-list - I like the `pairwise` function from the accepted answer.

Comment: @user1497892 please accept an answer. Or add comments why the answers don't solve your problem.

Answer (score 7):

```
s='''A 3.00 B 4.00 C 5.00 D 6.00
E 3.20 F 6.00 G 8.22
H 9.00 
I 9.23 J 89.2
K 32.344
'''

s=s.split()
d=dict(zip(s[::2], s[1::2]))
print d
```

---

In context:

```
my_dict = dict()
for line in reader.readlines():
    pairs = line.split()
    for key, value in zip(pairs[::2],pairs[1::2]):
        my_dict[key] = value # strip() not needed
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply, but is there a way to do this without modifying the input file by adding quotes ? The input file is being given to me.

Comment: Very nice, although I wouldn't use this exact code if I was the OP. It's always better to avoid reading the whole file at once when possible. This code is a very concise demo of a nice idea, though.

Comment: @user1497892, it's a [multiline string literal](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals). You don't need quotes in the input file. Also, to get the code to work, you need to know exactly what `readlines`, `readline` and `read` return on a file object. Please refer to the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using iterators that operates on a stream (and thus does not depending on reading the entire input first):

```
from itertools import izip

def group(iterable, n):
    """Yield iterable's items n at a time"""
    args = [iter(iterable)]*n
    return izip(*args)


def dictize(stream):
    r = {}
    for line in stream:
        for k,v in group(line.split(), 2):
            r[k] = v
    return r


from StringIO import StringIO

testinput = """A 3.00 B 4.00 C 5.00 D 6.00
E 3.20 F 6.00 G 8.22
H 9.00 
I 9.23 J 89.2
K 32.344"""

teststream = StringIO(testinput)

print dictize(teststream)
```

If you can use dictionary comprehensions, you can replace the `dictize` function with a one-liner:

```
print {k:v for line in teststream for k,v in group(line.split(),2)}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('candidate.txt', 'r') as reader:
    print dict(zip(*[iter(reader.read().split())]*2))
```

`With` the opened file stream called `reader` we `read` it as a whole and then `split` it in pieces by whitespace. Now we have a list of words which we transform to an `iter`ator and put it in a list and multiply it times `2` to make a list of two the same iterators. These are `zip`ped into pairs as input for a `dict`ionary.