# Python parsing, convert string to list of integers

Tags: python

I'm using `raw_input` for the user to type in an integer, for example `'123456'`.

How do I convert the string number by number so I can put them in a list: `[1,2,3,4,5]`?

Is the concept the same for two numbers like `12`,`34`,`56`?

Comment: To get numbers with two or more digits, you can refer to this Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628290/pairs-from-single-list

Comment: If you use raw_input to collect input, nothing prevents a user from entering invalid numbers so you also need to do error handling. This could be as simple as ignoring non-numeric digits. Be sure to include and an input (i.e., just hitting return) in your testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if user enter the numbers Consecutive you you can use the following list comprehension  :

```
>>> num=raw_input ("enter the numbers : ")
enter the numbers : 123459
>>> l=[int(i) for i in num]
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9]
```

and for numbers with len 2 that uses `,` as separator you need to split the input string then convert it to int  :

```
>>> num=raw_input ("enter the numbers : ")
enter the numbers : 12,34,56
>>> l=[int(i) for i in num.split(',')]
>>> l
[12, 34, 56]
```

---

But there is another way , if you dont want to convert the numbers you can put your `raw_input` function inside a loop :

```
>>> l=[]
>>> for i in range (5):
...  l.append(int(raw_input('enter %dth number :'%i)))
... 
enter 0th number :1
enter 1th number :5
enter 2th number :12
enter 3th number :56
enter 4th number :2345
>>> l
[1, 5, 12, 56, 2345]
```

and if you want to get number with len 2 from one input you can use slicing :

```
>>> num=raw_input ("enter the numbers : ")
enter the numbers : 1234424
>>> [int(num[i:i+2]) for i in range(0,len(num),2)]
[12, 34, 42, 4]
```

Comment: Nice solution. In the second case I was actually looking for a way to get [12,34,56] when a user use the same input as the example before(123456).

Comment: actually as a general formula `[num[i:i+n] for i in range(0,len(num),n)` split the string with `n` step ! read more http://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/

Comment: Thanks man! One more thing, how about the first example code [int(i) for i in number]? Is this a general formula or a short version?Source?

Comment: @John you're welcome , its list comprehension that make a loop trough your string and convert the elements in each loop to `int` , read more https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transform the string you read in from `raw_input` to a list of `int`...

```
number = raw_input("Number? ")
li = [int(i) for i in number]
```

There's only a little bit more work that you have to do to expand it to multiple digits, but I leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: How does [int(i) for i in number] exactly work? Is this a shortening of a longer code? Thx

Answer (score 0):

```
s = '123456'
print(map(int,s))

s = '12,34,56'
print(map(int,s.split(",")))

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[12, 34, 56]


s = '123456'
print([int("".join(tup)) for tup in zip(s[::2],s[1::2])]

[12, 34, 56]
```