# Iterating list python

Tags: python, iteration

I am having problems iterating in python. I have this structure:

```
a = [('f', 'f'),
 ('a', 'a'),
 ('e', 'e'),
 ('d', 'd'),
 ('e', 'e'),
 ('d', 'd'),
 ('b', 'b'),
 ('e', 'e'),
 ('d', 'd'),
 ('b', 'b'),
 ('a', 'a'),
 ('b', 'b'),
 ('g', 'g'),
 ('h', 'h'),
 ('c', 'c'),
 ('h', 'h'),
 ('a', 'a'),
 ('c', 'c'),
 ('g', 'g'),
 ('h', 'h'),
 ('g', 'g'),
 ('c', 'c'),
 ('f', 'f')]
```

And from that I want to get an output that gives me the first value of a parenthesis with the value of the next parenthesis, something like this:

```
b = [('f','a'), ('a','e'), ('e','d')etc..]
```

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pairs from single list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628290/pairs-from-single-list)

Comment: Sorry, marked the wrong question as duplicate, but if you search there are a few matching.

Comment: What should be the last tuple in the list?

Comment: @Mee: what if the tuple contains different elements for the first and second item, so `[('a','b'),('a','c'),...]` what is the expected output in that case?

Comment: @EricDuminil in this case the last tuple would be ('c','f').

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Well, with  the input i am working with that is not gonna happen. But let's suppose I want that the loop gives me the first value of a parenthesis with the first value of the next parenthesis, the expected output in that case would be ('a','a')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use some list comprehension:

```
[(x[0],y[0]) for x,y in zip(a,a[1:])]
```

Or even more elegantly:

```
[(x,y) for (x,_a),(y,_b) in zip(a,a[1:])]
```

You can avoid making a copy with the slicing, by using `islice` from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import islice

[(x,y) for (x,_a),(y,_b) in zip(a,islice(a,1,None))]
```

These all give:

```
>>> [(x,y) for (x,_a),(y,_b) in zip(a,a[1:])]
[('f', 'a'), ('a', 'e'), ('e', 'd'), ('d', 'e'), ('e', 'd'), ('d', 'b'), ('b', 'e'), ('e', 'd'), ('d', 'b'), ('b', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('b', 'g'), ('g', 'h'), ('h', 'c'), ('c', 'h'), ('h', 'a'), ('a', 'c'), ('c', 'g'), ('g', 'h'), ('h', 'g'), ('g', 'c'), ('c', 'f')]
```

Comment: Since the pairs always have the same two elements in the example, I'm not sure which elements should be picked in each tuple, and if they're really always the same in the input list.

Comment: @EricDuminil: As far as I know it is was in the body of the question, but somehow either my memory is failing, or the question has been edited immediately after posting.

Answer (score 1):

```
b = [(a[i][0], a[i+1][1]) for i in range(len(a)-1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

you may try this one

```
map(lambda x, y: (x[0], y[0]), a[:-1], a[1:])
```

output:

```
[('f', 'a'),('a', 'e'),('e', 'd'),('d', 'e'),...]
```