# finding way ids for list of osm nodes in shortest path

Tags: python, osmnx, vehicle-routing

In a route, we get a list of all the nodes from the source to destination.

```
route = nx.shortest_path(G,origin_node,desitination_node, weight='length')
```

Is it possible to get all the osm way ids from source to destination?

Comment: can you have a look @gboeing

Comment: can some body have a look. i cant find a way out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the route is a list of nodes. Iterate through this list pairwise to get edge (u, v) tuples (for instance see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4628446/7321942). Look up those edge tuples in the graph to get the constituent OSM way IDs corresponding to those edges.