# Online computation of coverage time for a time range

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have a time range, it could be represented by a video as the time when it starts(0 s) and the time it ended. For instance, with a video that lasts 1 min I have a time range that goes from 0s to 60s.

Suppose I have an online stream that sends me time intervals like this:

```
[0, 10]
[8, 14]
[2, 3]
[20, 25]
```

Suppose that these intervals represents time passed playing a video. I would like to compute, each time a new interval arrives, the effective time the video was played without repetition.

It should be something like this:

```
[0, 10]
#time_played = 10s
[8, 14]
#time_played = 14s because [0,10]+[8,14] -> [0,14] is the effective time interval
[2, 3]
#time_played = 14s because this time interval has already been covered
[20, 25]
#time_played = 19s because [0, 14] + [20, 25] makes 19s the video was effectively played
```

I cannot find a solution because I don't event know what is the problem definition. What do you think could be a clever way to solve this problem using `python`

Answer (score 1):

You could append all the times that have passed to an array, then get the length of the array like so.

```
times = []
def get_time(interval = None): # If we don't pass the interval it will return the current time passed
    if interval:
        for time in range(interval[0], interval[1]):
            if time not in times: # Don't append to the array if we already have the time value
                times.append(time)
    return len(times) # Return the length of the array of times


print(get_time([0, 10]))
#time_played = 10s
print(get_time([8, 14]))
#time_played = 14s because [0,10]+[8,14] -> [0,14] is the effective time interval
print(get_time([2, 3]))
#time_played = 14s because this time interval has already been covered
print(get_time([20, 25]))
#time_played = 19s because [0, 14] + [20, 25] makes 19s the video was effectively played

## Expected output:
## 10
## 14
## 14
## 19
```

Hope this is helpful

Comment: Thank you, this solution solves the problem. Nonetheless, it needs to be admitted that this solution is memory-consuming because you need to store all the time instants, while I think you could store only the extrems. 

Upvoted, but I am waiting for some stunning, hyper-clever solution :D

Comment: I have posted a new answer which I think should sort the memory issue. I have posted it as new rather than editing this one due to the fact that this one may be simpler for a beginner to understand, so if a someone has a similar question they can better understand how this works

Answer (score 0):

Here's my new answer.
The get time function does a few things:
1, calculating the time- The functon creates a local list called `times` and appends the time values to it (as in the previous answer, but this time we use a local list so it isn't as memory consuming), factoring in all the `previous_intervals` and the intervals passed to the function. It then saves the time played to a variable called `time_played`. This is what will be returned later.
2, calculating the `previous_intervals`- The `previous_intervals` variable is cleared then, if the number of times are greater than 0 (to avoid `pop(0)` raising an `IndexError`, if not then the `previous_intervals` are empty anyway) the program will sort the times and find out all the intervals needed to create the list of times that are there. It will then save to `previous_intervals` for next time the function is run
3, returning- the program returns the `time_played` variable we created earlier. It doesn't return `len(times)` as since we popped out an item this will be wrong in most circumstances; it won't, however, be wrong if no seconds have passed (i.e. the interval passed was `[0, 0]`) so we can't return `len(times) + 1` either.

Special thanks to Diarmuid O'Briain who's answer to [Pairs from single list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628290/pairs-from-single-list) helped me to write the `previous_intervals` calculation

```py
previous_intervals = []
def get_time(*intervals):
    global previous_intervals
    times = []
    intervals = list(intervals) + previous_intervals
    for interval in intervals:
        for time in range(interval[0], interval[1]):
            if time not in times:
                times.append(time)

    time_played = len(times)

    previous_intervals = []
    if len(times) > 0:
        times.sort()
        lastTime = times.pop(0)
        important_intervals = [lastTime]
        for time in times:
            if time != lastTime + 1:
                important_intervals.append(lastTime + 1)
                important_intervals.append(time)
            lastTime = time
        important_intervals.append(lastTime + 1)
        while(important_intervals):
            start_time = important_intervals.pop(0)
            end_time = important_intervals.pop(0)
            previous_intervals.append([start_time,end_time])


    return time_played

print(get_time([0, 0]))
#time_played = 0s, not 1s as would happen if we returned len(times) with correction for the missing values
print(get_time([0, 0], [1, 1]))
#time_played = 0s, we can now pass multiple intervals. ([0, 0] = No time passed + [1, 1] = No time passed, so even though this may look odd it's totally correct)
print(get_time([0, 10]))
#time_played = 10s
print(get_time([8, 14]))
#time_played = 14s because [0,10]+[8,14] -> [0,14] is the effective time interval
print(get_time([2, 3]))
#time_played = 14s because this time interval has already been covered
print(get_time([20, 25]))
#time_played = 19s because [0, 14] + [20, 25] makes 19s the video was effectively played

## Expected output:
## 0
## 0
## 10
## 14
## 14
## 19
```

Hope this is helpful