# Python How to insert characters in every other listed item

Tags: python, list

```py
list = ['username1', 'https://link.com/bsd3nj', 'username2', 'https://link.com/a32fs2', 'username3', 'https://link.com/cfzxso']

sort_list = '* {}'.format('- \n'.join(list))
```

Output:

```
* username1- 
https://link.com/bsd3nj-
username2- 
https://link.com/a32fs2-
username3- 
https://link.com/cfzxso-
username4- 
https://link.com/a235jsh-
username5- 
https://link.com/123nls2-
```

This is what I have, but its not what I want happen.

I want the list to be like

```
* username1 - https://link.com/bsd3nj
* username2 - https://link.com/a32fs2
* username3 - https://link.com/cfzxso
* username4 - https://link.com/a235jsh
* username5 - https://link.com/123nls2
```

I have thought about doing `.split()` but there isnt really any pattern. The username is random so it the link ending.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pairs from single list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628290/pairs-from-single-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use a built-in name for a variable : `list`, it'll save you from errors a day if you don't think about it

---

That said, to make pairs from consecutive elements there is several options ([listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628290/pairs-from-single-list#answers))

Here's one : `zip(values[::2], values[1::2])`

```
for name, link in zip(values[::2], values[1::2]):
    print(f"*{name} - {link}")

# or shorter

sort_list = "\n".join([f"*{name} - {link}" for name, link in zip(values[::2], values[1::2])])
print(sort_list, "\n\n")
```

---

The slice notation `[start:end:increment]` is here

- `[::2]` : all values from start, 2 by 2 => all the names
- `[1::2]` : all values except first one, 2 by 2 => all the links

The [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) operation *make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables.*

```
zip([1,2,3], ['a', 'b', 'c']) # => ((1,'a'), (2, 'b'), ('3, 'c'))
```

So you have a list of names and a list of links, and you pair them

```
print(values[::2])  # ['username1', 'username2', 'username3']
print(values[1::2])  # ['https://link.com/bsd3nj', 'https://link.com/a32fs2', 'https://link.com/cfzxso']
print(list(zip(values[::2], values[1::2]))) # [('username1', 'https://link.com/bsd3nj'), ('username2', 'https://link.com/a32fs2'), ('username3', 'https://link.com/cfzxso')]
```

Comment: `You may never use a built-in name for a variable : list` - you may **but** it is a bad idea.

Comment: Can you please explain it a bit better for a beginner? The zip() part? Reading the "Pairs from single list" is kinda confusing for me.

Answer (score 1):

Using an iterator is an efficient solution:

```
def joined(given_list):
    iterator = iter(given_list)
    return '\n'.join(['* ' + c + ' - ' + next(iterator) for c in iterator])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here as a one-liner:

```
l = ['username1', 'https://link.com/bsd3nj', 'username2', 'https://link.com/a32fs2', 'username3', 'https://link.com/cfzxso']

out = '* {}'.format('\n* '.join(list(map(" - ".join, zip(l[::2], l[1::2])))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `numpy` and `pandas`.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

l = ['username1', 'https://link.com/bsd3nj', 'username2', 'https://link.com/a32fs2', 'username3', 'https://link.com/cfzxso']

l = np.array(l)  # convert to numpy array so I can reshape it into two column
l = l.reshape(-1,2)
l = pd.DataFrame(l) # convert to data frame so I can easily use operator.

l = "*  " + l[0] +  " - " + l[1]
l = l.values.tolist()  # convert back to list
l = "\n".join(l) # convert to string with line break.
print(l)
```

Output is:

```
*  username1 - https://link.com/bsd3nj
*  username2 - https://link.com/a32fs2
*  username3 - https://link.com/cfzxso
```