# Extract data between patterns in python

Tags: python, regex

Considering I  have below string,

```
~m~90~m~{Somestringof length 90}~m~20~m~{Some string of len 20}~m~10~m~{Somestringof length 10}
```

Need to extract the strings between the pattern **~m~\d~m~** one by one

One solution I found is something like

```
my_pattern = re.compile("~m~\d+~m~")
data_arr = my_pattern.finditer(result)
if data_arr:
   get the indexes of pattern and search in original string
```

This solution is not optimal, I am sure there must be a better way to do it.

Comment: @anubhava, doing that prints the pattern itself and not the string in between

Comment: @JvdV let me try that, similar solution given in the answer by ti7

Comment: `re.split(pattern, text)` will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split on the `~m~`, which will get you both the numbers and the strings!

```py
>>> "~m~90~m~{Somestringof length 90}~m~20~m~{Some string of len 20}~m~10~m~{Somestringof length 10}".split("~m~")
['', '90', '{Somestringof length 90}', '20', '{Some string of len 20}', '10', '{Somestringof length 10}']
```

If you're certain you'll always have that same form, you can clean it up and take [Pairs from single list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628290/pairs-from-single-list) (note `itertools.izip` is simply `zip` in Python3)

```py
>>> src_text = "~m~90~m~{Somestringof length 90}~m~20~m~{Some string of len 20}~m~10~m~{Somestringof length 10}"
>>> def pairwise(t):
...     it = iter(t)
...     return zip(it,it)
...
>>> for textlen, text in pairwise(filter(None, src_text.split("~m~"))):
...   print(f"{textlen}: {text}")
...
90: {Somestringof length 90}
20: {Some string of len 20}
10: {Somestringof length 10}
```

Note that the results of `.split()`-ing will be strings, so you should explicitly convert the numeric length to be `int()` if you need it as one

Comment: wow, this seems to be as expected. Thanks