# How to convert a float list to a tuple list by pair?

Tags: python

Assuming that the length of the list is always even, what is the best way to convert the following list:

```
points = [[1437.8552278820375, 1187.3458445040214, 1084.396782841823, 1245.6836461126006, 1104.9865951742627, 1430.9919571045577, 1458.4450402144773, 1307.4530831099196]]
```

to a tuple list such as:

```
points = [(1437.8552278820375, 1187.3458445040214), (1084.396782841823, 1245.6836461126006), (1104.9865951742627, 1430.9919571045577), (1458.4450402144773, 1307.4530831099196)]
```

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pairs from single list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628290/pairs-from-single-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
points = zip(points[0][::2], points[0][1::2])
list(points)
```